# How to create a dataframe with the text from a set pdf files in R?

Tags: r, pdf

I have a set of pdf files: 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf.....n.pdf.
I want to create a dataframe, with the text of file per row in a column and the name of file in other column.
I can extract the pdf's texts with pdftools package, but I can't create a dataframe. 
The result expected is some thus: 
[image]

Comment: What format does `pdftools` give you? This seems like not a question about `[pdf]`, since your problem is post-extraction. Please provide a sample of the object returned by `pdftools`, perhaps with `dput(head(x))` or similar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help,
My problem is that I need a dataframe with all the content of pdf file in a row, but the outcome that I get with pdf_text() of pdftools, is one page of that file per row. 
The outcome expected for the dataframe is: number of rows = number of pdf files.

Comment: J.S, I understand, but it is unclear how to proceed with what you have provided. If the first column of the frame (pls do not post images of data!) is truly just a counter with no indication of file, then there is no way to know to which file each row belongs. This suggests something needs to be done with the command you are using. In addition to `dput(head(x))`, please provide code you used to create this odd `data.frame`. Bottom line, the question is unanswerable in its current state.